# hover overlayed text on an image bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

I have an overlayng text and navigation arrows on an image, they appear when a **mouseover** event is fired and hide when the mouse leaves the image.

The bug is that the overlay text is not a part of the image, so when i mouse over it, it starts flashing (because when the text hides, the mouse is positioned on the image, and that fires the **mouseover** event and the text shows up again)

This is my current JavaScript logic:

```
$('#container img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.discr').show();
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.discr').hide();
    })
})
```

For better understanding this is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfkk78cn/)  and here is what i expect: the overlay text does not flash when the mouse is over it, it acts like when the mouse is over the image only.

Comment: You should target `#container` instead of the `img`. But you know you can do this with just CSS, right ?

Comment: just css, you mean when a hover on an element, another element shows up ? how so ?

Comment: posted the method as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**JavaScript version**

```
$('#container').mouseover(function () {
    var $controls = $(this).find('.discr');
    $controls.show();
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        $controls.hide();
    })
})
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/b6hjm3t1/

**Pure CSS version without JavaScript**

You can have the same results just with CSS without the using JavaScript just by adding to the CSS:

```
#container:hover .discr {
  display:block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t6hf0fqg/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this does what you're looking for. I've modified the code a little bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfkk78cn/1/

```
$( "#container" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.discr').show();
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.discr').hide();
  });
```

Comment: what does find exactly do ?
can you explain me your logic please ? i don't want just a solution .. i want educate myself, thanks

Comment: @Amine - jQuery find is looking for elements within #container that have the class of '.discr'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution for the same effect.

The important part is the you can do `#container:hover .discr` which will target the `.discr` elements when the `#container` is hovered.

```css
img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
}
#container {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid green;
}
.discr {
    position:absolute;
    color:red;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}

/*ADDED THIS RULE*/
#container:hover .discr{
    display:block;
}
.next {
    left:185px;
}
.next, .prev {
    bottom:50%;
    width:15px;
    border-radius:9px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <img src='http://goo.gl/Rwf5SG' />
    
    <div class='discr prev'>&lt;</div>
    <div class='discr next'>&gt;</div>
    <div class='discr'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```